# IP vs MAC address nslookup command

Tags: ip, nslookup

I am working with Unix and I used nslookup on a machine at my college.
I got the following output:
Server: ***.***.**.**
Address: ***.***.**.**#**

Name: (name of the machine)
Address: ***.***.**.**

With the *s replaced with the actual numbers.

Which of these numbers is the IP address and which is the MAC address?

Answer (score 0):

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the IP

xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx is the MAC address